# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the filename popover menu in Preview, Pages, etc.?

Tags: keyboard, preview

I'm referring to the popover menu that opens when clicking the little down arrow next to the file name in some apps.[image]

I use that extensively—it would be convenient if there were a keyboard shortcut to open it, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: What's your intent? To change the name of the existing document, to make a copy under a new name, or just save over the original?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of one, but you can of course use Command I (Get Info) in the Finder to change the name or assign Tags.

Answer (score -1):

Command + S when you have the file open. In finder maybe Command + space. Those are the only options I know...